# TastyPie apply authentication only to PUT/POST

Tags: tastypie

How do apply authentication & authorization to PUT and POST methods in TastyPie? I know we can define authentication and authorization in Meta inner class on the resource but how do i let these two methods ONLY to pass thru authentication and authorization layer. I interested in SessionAuthentication and DjangoAuthrization btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create class based on DjangoAuthrization (add it to Meta then) and override two functions:

```
def read_list(self, object_list, bundle):
    return object_list

def read_detail(self, object_list, bundle):     
    return True
```